# Change date format of date filter in all admin grids

Tags: magento2, order-grid, datepicker

I'm a magento newbie. My client asked us to change date format of date filter in all admin grids. He needs to change date format to display as **dd/mm/yyyy**.

Can anyone help to solve this? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Stores->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog->Date & Time Custom Options->Date Fields Order`
Uncheck the `Use system value` and change the format as you wish.